# ng test command is not working with angular 8 and Jest

Tags: angular, jestjs, karma-jasmine

I am facing a issue when i try to run test cases with "`npm run test`" command with Angular 8 and Jest

I am trying to migrate from `Karma/jasmine` framework to Jest and also upgrading angular version to 8.

But `npm` run test command is throwing the below error

> File not found: /src/tsconfig.spec.json (resolved as:
>   D:\app-jest\src\tsconfig.spec.json)
>
> at ConfigSet.resolvePath (node_modules/ts-jest/dist/config/config->set.js:712:19)

Package.json

```
   {
      scripts": {
          "ng": "ng",
          "start": "ng serve",
          "test": "jest"
     }
```

jest.config.js

```
 module.exports = {
    preset: 'jest-preset-angular',
    roots: ['src'],
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ["./src/setup-jest.ts"]
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the quick fix
Move `tsconfig.spec.json` back to src.
Update `jest.config.js:`

Newer version has this fixed. Refer following thread

https://github.com/briebug/jest-schematic/issues/12

Comment: I mimicked the same process still couldn't find tsconfig.spec.json when I try running "jest: command or "jest --watch". ng test works but I want to make use of jest --watch. I'm very new to unit testing and jest.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is my suggestion:

**1. Use this statement in your `package.json` file. Obviously, you may need to change the files' path.**

```
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-preset-angular",
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "<rootDir>/src/setupJest.ts"
    ],
    "globals": {
      "ts-jest": {
        "tsConfig": "./tsconfig.spec.json",
        "diagnostics": false,
        "stringifyContentPathRegex": "\\.html$",
        "astTransformers": ["<rootDir>/node_modules/jest-preset-angular/InlineHtmlStripStylesTransformer"]
      }
    }
  }
```

**2. I had to remove `test.ts` file from `src` folder. There was a conflict related to this jasmine script.**

**3. I also added the following statement in to the `tsconfig.app.json`**

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    //...
    "types": [
      "jest"
    ]
  }
```

I hope that helps you and I recommend you to read this [article](https://itnext.io/how-i-do-configure-jest-to-test-my-angular-8-project-2bd84a21d725)